# Python: Can I use if else function when creating a new dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a beginner in python.

I need to find out what function should I use in order to create a new dataset (df2) for empty original dataset (df). For example,

```
df2 = df['count_days'].dt.days >= 1
```

When I don't have no days to count in the dataset (empty data), I get an error.

Can I use if else statement to resolve this issue?
For example:

```
if df['count_days'].dt.days >= 1
   df2
else 
   print("No Data")
```

BTW - I sometimes would have empty dataset because there is no record available.

Thank you!

Comment: Please be explicit, provide a reproducible example of `df` and the matching expected output

Comment: you could use `try except`

Comment: `if df2.shape[0] > 0:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use the if and else statements:

```
import pandas as pd

if df.empty:
    print("No Data")
else:
    df2 = df['count_days'].dt.days >= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of working around it, you could create a dataframe which doesn't produce these errors:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'count_days': pd.Series([], dtype='timedelta64[ns]')})
df['count_days'].dt.days >= 1 # no error
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to fill data, [NaN `np.nan` (or equivalent "not a number")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) or `.nat` ("not a time") are frequently used when you need to fill data that does not exist - this is part of [IEEE 754 specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':[3,4]})
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
>>> df["c"] = np.nan  # NumPy
>>> df
   a  b   c
0  1  3 NaN
1  2  4 NaN
>>> pd.merge(df, pd.DataFrame({'a':[5],'b':[6],'c':[7]}), 'outer')
   a  b    c
0  1  3  NaN
1  2  4  NaN
2  5  6  7.0
>>> df[df['c'].isna()]  # filter NaNs
   a  b   c
0  1  3 NaN
1  2  4 NaN
>>> df[~df['c'].isna()]
   a  b    c
2  5  6  7.0
```

In Python, if you have an object that you need to exist, but do nothing, frequently `None` is the correct object

```py
df = None
...  # intermediate logic
if df is None:  # special case
    ...
```